# SQL to calculate the average amount paid in the last 7 days

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a table with 2 columns visited and the amount paid

```
visited         amount paid
-------------------------
2018-04-01      100
2018-04-02      200
2018-04-03      300
```

I want to get the average amount paid in the last 7 days (today and last 6 days) along with visited and amount paid in result:

Output:

```
visited         amount      average of last 7 days
---------------------------------------------------
2018-04-01      100         100
2018-04-02      200         150
2018-04-03      300         200
```

**Explanation:**

```
Row 1 : average amount = 100/1 = 100
Row 2 : average amount = (100 + 200)/2 = 150
Row 3 : average amount = (100 + 200 + 300)/3 = 200
```

I am trying this using MySQL or Oracle database, anything is fine.

Comment: MySQL Version???

Comment: @SalmanA mysql version is 5

Comment: To be clear - do you want a solution which runs on **both** platforms? Or just one and you don't care which?

Comment: @APC, anything is fine for me, MySQL or Oracle

Comment: is there a row for each day, or can there be gaps?

Comment: @OldProgrammer, there can be gaps also

Comment: I think the best answer for this question is the answer given by @gordon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a correlated sub-query in MySQL 5.x:

```
SELECT visited, amount_paid, (
    SELECT AVG(amount_paid)
    FROM t AS x
    WHERE x.visited >= t.visited - INTERVAL 6 DAY
    AND   x.visited <= t.visited
) AS 7_day_avg
FROM t
```

In MySQL 8 and Oracle you could use window functions.

Comment: What do you mean by *window functions will not help if there are gaps between visits*? Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b1807f604ba0bf8a700716bcf1ee5db1

Comment: @forpas that was incorrect and I just removed it. Having said that, in the fiddle the `03-Nov-2019` row should count `31-Oct-2019` but it does not. I have revised it based on Gordon's answer https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=08b9ed157f08ed7610dc4776c5aa66c7.

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle with `AVG()` analytic function:

```
select t.*, avg(t."amount paid") over (order by t."visited") as "average of last 7 days"
from tablename t
where t."visited" >= to_date('08-11-2019', 'dd-MM-yyyy') - 7
and t."visited" <= to_date('08-11-2019', 'dd-MM-yyyy')
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=78a2f40329a5c6fa25084f5427defa25).

Comment: for example, let's say I take a record with date as 8th Nov 2019, then I want to consider 7 days earlier from 8th Nov 2019 to calculate average, but above query uses `current_date ` so will this satisfy this condition

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want a cumulative running average.  If so, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
       avg(amount_paid) over (order by visited
                              range between interval '6' day preceding and current row
                             )
from t;
```

Both Oracle and MySQL 8+ support this syntax.